# Nested CSS Descendant Selectors With Adjacent Sibling Combinator

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using SCSS but I don't think that's particularly relevant to the results I'm seeing.

I was initially hoping to use the more compact `& + &`, but I'm guessing `+` isn't being interpreted correctly when both sides are descendant selectors.

However, `& + .child` does seem to deliver the desired result of selecting each `.child` that is a sibling of a `.child` under `.parent`.

The following SCSS:

```
.parent {
  .child {
    & + & {
      padding: 0;
    }

    & + .child {
      margin: 0;        
    }
  }
}
```

produces:

```
.parent .child + .parent .child {
  padding: 0;
}
.parent .child + .child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Is there some way to group descendant selectors, or am I stuck with the second option above?

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS, so you cannot target the adjacent parent based on the first child with `.child + .parent`. You can target it based on the first *parent*, however, as those elements would be siblings. This would be something like `.parent + .parent .child`. The second approach you showcased is probably what I would consider 'best' to achieve what you're trying to do; I don't think it's any less descriptive than the first attempt.

Comment: Thanks.  I was originally hoping to go with `.parent .child + .parent .child` because we're also using `stylelint` and it produces a `no-descending-specificity` error when using `.parent .child + .child` along with another set of selectors that equates to `.another-parent .child + .child`.